# How to check if map exists in array at specific position

Tags: arrays, typescript, dictionary

I declared an array as:

```
public carOptions: Array<Map<number, Map<number, string>>> = [];
```

I am trying to determin is my array has any data stored at a specific `index` position (e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc)

My first try was for

```
if (this.carOptions[index] === undefined) {...}`,
```

but this yields `Expression is always false.

My 2nd thought was for checking just

```
if (this.carOptions[index]) {...}
```

but this is "falsy checking" (null, 0, etc). Not ideal, at all.

My 3rd thought was to switch declaration to

```
public carOptions: Array<Map<number, Map<number, string>> | undefined> = [];
```

This is both ugly and requires non-null assertion for the TSLint.

Therefore, my question stands. Is there a better way to check if my array has any element at position `index` ?

Comment: Could you use `typeof this.carOptions[index] === 'undefined'` ?

Comment: The type signature `Array<Map<number, Map<number, string>>>` assumes that the array doesn't contain `undefined` elements. If this type signature is correct, you only need to check `index < this.carOptions.length`. If it's not correct, I'd consider using the 3rd option (possibly with a type alias for brevity).

Comment: @p.s.w.g this might work! It's assumed the array doesn't contain `undefined` elements. The check is necessary to decide if a new map should be pushed into the array, or if there's already a map and just a new value should be pushed (for that specific position)

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but it seems like you might need something other than an array. Perhaps another Map, e.g. `if (!this.carOptions.has(index)) { ... }`? On the other hand, all those nested maps suggest to me that you might need to rethink your approach, but I can't say for sure.